# How expensive was seafare in the Middle Ages?

Tags: travel

I know that travel wasn't very common, but I'm wondering how much it would cost for a well-off traveler to arrange passage on a sailing ship.

I'm looking for a price circa 1300, assuming the ship is already headed in the desired direction (carrying other cargo). The journey would be short (couple weeks), such as Britain to the Mediterranean.

I'm guessing it would be on the order of a few shillings a person, but couldn't find any sources on the subject. The closest I could find was in the 1800's, where prices were around 30 pounds, but that was with a full cabin, a lot of inflation, and may have been transatlantic.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3678264?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Am interesting resource, but doesn't answer the question. The earl in the document was accompanied by a large number of retainers, and so had to hire ships for his purposes. I'm looking for how much it would cost for a lone traveler, or maybe a handful of people, to book passage on a vessel carrying cargo. (And not cargo for the traveler.) It also doesn't give much in the way of numbers, at least in the first half of the essay.

Comment: Unretained individuals travelling is fairly anachronistic.

Comment: I'd imagine that travel of the sort described would have been such a rarity that no meaningful table of prices would exist. The traveller and the ship owner/master would determine a price at the time (possibly depending on whether the traveller could work his passage or provide some other service).

Comment: I've read that, while certainly not available to common people, there were people who would travel for a variety of purposes, from pilgrimages to merchant/banking business, to messengers. I can imagine that there wouldn't be a standard table of prices, but I was hoping someone might be able to offer a ballpark estimate of what a typical negotiated price may have been. Though the point of negotiating labor for travel is a good one.